# Java 7 WatchService: avoiding an infinite loop of events when changing the event source in handler

Tags: java, nio, java-7, watchservice

Basically, I'm using the fresh new Java's 7 WatchService to monitor a directory.

I have a chain of handlers listening to every IO event issued by the directory.

The problem is some of the handlers need to change the reason of those IO events (== files) in some way. For example, if somebody puts a file into the monitored folder, one of the handlers might change it's extension, append something to it's file name, or whatever.

Those actions of course trigger new IO events and the aforementioned handlers get them. Then they once again do their changes. This obviously leads to an infinite loop...

Does Java offer any way to handle this kind of situation? If not, how would you deal with this?

Basically I'd like to run my event handlers only when the event wasn't caused by those handlers' action.

**UPDATE:** As for the solution, I'd rather make a change only the in the main event router's code than worry about this in every handler I write ("handler makes a change only if didn't do it before").

Comment: I suspect you would have to keep track of which events you want to ignore in your handlers based on your previous actions. The easiest way would be if Mark Elliot's answer is possible.

Answer (score 4):

This only leads to an infinite loop if there's no base case.

Suppose people put files in the directory with extension '.bar', and you want extension '.foo', well, your handler makes that change *if and only if* the current extension is '.bar'.

Even though your handler will still get an event for the new `<file>.foo`, you can discard it, stopping the "infinite" event propagation.

Comment: Still the question has merit. Let's say you want to and action on all files put in a watched directory, then do an operation which might not be easily detected. So you only want to take action on modifications by external callers.

Comment: @jontro: the point is that for cases where you are *self-generating* the events, and that that generation might cause infinite loops, you *must* have a base case, just like recursion.

Comment: Yeah, there's of course that but like jontro said - taking actions only when there's been an external caller seems like a reasonable and possible scenario. I'd rather make a change only the in the main event router's code than worry about this in every handler I write.

Comment: @PawełBara, If someone else modifies the file, and then *you* modify the file, and *that* generates the event, it's exactly what I'm describing. You need a **base** case. And that base case can only reasonably exist where you have knowledge of what can cause a firing of the local event to occur, e.g. in the handler.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a new Thread every time your code handling an event would trigger a new event. Inside your event handle check if the changed file needs a rename, if yes start a new thread doing the rename, if not return from the event.
Doing it that way avoid infinite loops, since the event handling code exits in any way.

Comment: A new Thread? Threads take up a lot of system memory and it is specifically recommended to **not** use more threads than you need. Seriously, don't do this, it won't fix it anyway.